RPi cross compilation with arm-linux-gnueabihi libstdc++ symbol difference
Cross-compiling through Docker on x86 system.
Normal programs work fine but when I go to use std::filesystem which seems to use shared_ptr I get the following issue
./package: symbol lookup error: ./package: undefined symbol: _ZNSt12__shared_ptrINSt10filesystem7__cxx114_DirELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC1EOS5_, version GLIBCXX_3.4.26


Docker base image: FROM debian:bullseye
Both RPi and host and have same versions

Target
$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

$ g++ --version
g++ (Raspbian 10.2.1-6+rpi1) 10.2.1 20210110

Host
$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --version
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110

Further investigation found these differences:
Target:
$ nm -D /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 | grep _ZNSt12__shared_ptrINSt10filesystem7__cxx114_DirELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE
0012b50c W _ZNSt12__shared_ptrINSt10filesystem7__cxx114_DirELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE1EEaSEOS5_@@GLIBCXX_3.4.26
0012b4e8 W _ZNSt12__shared_ptrINSt10filesystem7__cxx114_DirELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE1EEC1EOS5_@@GLIBCXX_3.4.26

Host:
$ nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep _ZNSt12__shared_ptrINSt10filesystem7__cxx114_DirELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE          
000000000014c4a0 W _ZNSt12__shared_ptrINSt10filesystem7__cxx114_DirELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC1EOS5_@@GLIBCXX_3.4.26
000000000014c410 W _ZNSt12__shared_ptrINSt10filesystem7__cxx114_DirELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4.26

Differences: target=E1EEaSEOS5 host=E2EEC1EOS5.
ChatGPT says this relates to the constructor version. No idea how to fix it other than static linking.
How could these be different and is there a way around other than static linking?
EDIT demangled names
Target
$ c++filt _ZNSt12__shared_ptrINSt10filesystem7__cxx114_DirELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE1EEaSEOS5_
std::__shared_ptr<std::filesystem::__cxx11::_Dir, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)1>::operator=(std::__shared_ptr<std::filesystem::__cxx11::_Dir, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)1>&&)
$ c++filt _ZNSt12__shared_ptrINSt10filesystem7__cxx114_DirELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE1EEC1EOS5_
std::__shared_ptr<std::filesystem::__cxx11::_Dir, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)1>::__shared_ptr(std::__shared_ptr<std::filesystem::__cxx11::_Dir, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)1>&&)


Host
$ c++filt _ZNSt12__shared_ptrINSt10filesystem7__cxx114_DirELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC1EOS5_
std::__shared_ptr<std::filesystem::__cxx11::_Dir, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr(std::__shared_ptr<std::filesystem::__cxx11::_Dir, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>&&)
$ c++filt _ZNSt12__shared_ptrINSt10filesystem7__cxx114_DirELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC1Ev
std::__shared_ptr<std::filesystem::__cxx11::_Dir, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr()



Please look up the demangled form of the unresolved symbols. You can use c++filt.

added the demangled names. the unresolved symbol on the target prints the same as the host (std::__shared_ptr<std::filesystem::__cxx11::_Dir, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr(std::__shared_ptr<std::filesystem::__cxx11::_Dir, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>&&))

Difference seems to come from the _Lock_policy which I bet has to do with the target architecture potentially not supporting atomic instructions. See https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/52e56eef53b444b5b86c3492e5a7a079c010c1c9/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/ext/concurrence.h#L54 and https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/52e56eef53b444b5b86c3492e5a7a079c010c1c9/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/acinclude.m4#L3978
